# Updating record using CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_PriceUpdate
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@PriceRuleID INT = NULL,
@CategoryID INT = NULL,
@SiteID INT = NULL
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
WITH PriceCTE(ProductID, CategoryID, SalePrice)
AS
(
    SELECT 
        ProductID, CategoryID, SalePrice
    FROM
        CAT_Products
    WHERE
        CategoryID = @CategoryID
)
SELECT ProductID,categoryID,SalePrice FROM PriceCTE

DECLARE 
    @Value DECIMAL(32,2),
    @Type NVARCHAR(5),
    @Inc_Dec NVARCHAR(5)

SELECT @Value = value FROM VB_PriceRule WHERE ID = @PriceRuleID AND SiteId = @SiteID
SELECT @Type = [type] FROM VB_PriceRule WHERE ID = @PriceRuleID AND SiteId = @SiteID
SELECT @Inc_Dec = Inc_Dec FROM VB_PriceRule WHERE ID = @PriceRuleID AND SiteId = @SiteID

IF(@Type = '+')
    BEGIN
        IF(@Inc_Dec = '%')
            BEGIN
            --print 'MSG'
                UPDATE CAT_Products SET
                    SalePrice = SalePrice + (@Value/100*SalePrice)
                FROM PriceCTE
                WHERE
                    CategoryID = @CategoryID
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                UPDATE CAT_Products SET
                    SalePrice = SalePrice + @Value                      
                FROM PriceCTE
                WHERE
                    CategoryID = @CategoryID
            END
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF(@Inc_Dec = '%')
            BEGIN
                UPDATE CAT_Products SET
                    SalePrice = SalePrice - (@Value/100*SalePrice)                      
                FROM PriceCTE
                WHERE
                    CategoryID = @CategoryID
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                UPDATE CAT_Products SET
                    SalePrice = SalePrice - @Value
                FROM PriceCTE
                WHERE
                    CategoryID = @CategoryID
            END
    END
END
```

Q) Here is my query...I want to update the sales price of CAT_Products. As per the conditions using CTE. But it gives me the results as "Invalid object name PriceCTE"

Comment: @mu "set nocount on" is SQL Server specific, so I added the tag for that.

Comment: @mu I didn't think Sybase supported CTEs.

Comment: It is likely that you confused two variables: `@Inc_Dec` should probably be compared with `'+'` and `@Type` with `'%'`.

Comment: Actually, '+' ,'%' are the values coming from database.

Comment: Yes, I thought just as much. But is `+` actually stored in the `Type` column and `%` in `Inc_Dec`, and *not* the other way round? I absolutely do not mind if they are. Just thought I'd tell you about my doubts, in case you *did* mix them up.

Answer (score 4):

A CTE is valid within the scope of the single statement it is defined in. Therefore, since `PriceCTE` is defined within the scope of the `SELECT … FROM PriceCTE` statement, it cannot be accessed in your UPDATEs.

The following solution combines the CTE definition with UPDATE. It also combines all your updates in one statement.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_PriceUpdate
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@PriceRuleID INT = NULL,
@CategoryID INT = NULL,
@SiteID INT = NULL
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN

DECLARE 
    @Value DECIMAL(32,2),
    @Type NVARCHAR(5),
    @Inc_Dec NVARCHAR(5);

SELECT
    @Value = value,
    @Type = [type],
    @Inc_Dec = Inc_Dec
FROM
    VB_PriceRule
WHERE
    ID = @PriceRuleID
AND SiteId = @SiteID;

WITH PriceCTE(ProductID, CategoryID, SalePrice)
AS
(
    SELECT
        ProductID, CategoryID, SalePrice
    FROM
        CAT_Products
    WHERE
        CategoryID = @CategoryID
)
UPDATE PriceCTE
SET
    SalePrice = SalePrice + @Value *
    (
        CASE @Type WHEN '+' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END *
        CASE @Inc_Dec WHEN '%' THEN SalePrice / 100 ELSE 1 END
    )

END
```

I didn't change variable names, but, as I said in a comment to your question, two variables, `@Inc_Dec` and `@Type`, do look as if they need to trade places. I'm merely judging by their names, in particular, by the `@Inc_Dec` name: that one is more likely to mean `+` or `-`, rather than `%` or whatever is the opposite value. But that's just an assumption, and you must know your stuff better, naturally.